# Visual Studio Code Flutter Cannot Update Dart SDK

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, sdk, dart

> Because depends on cupertino_icons >=1.0.1 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.

whenever I tried to `flutter run`, `flutter pub get`, `flutter pub upgrade`, I got this return in console.. I also have tried `flutter update-packages` it returns

> Flutter is already up to date on channel stable   Flutter 1.22.5 •
> channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git  Framework •
> revision 7891006299 (3 weeks ago) • 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800   Engine
> • revision ae90085a84   Tools • Dart 2.10.4

How can I update Dart SDK?

Comment: First, you already have the latest versions for Flutter and Dart. Second, this is not a problem of Dart version, read [this page](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_icons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use 1.0.0 version of cupertino in your pubspec.yaml. I think there is a problem with new version of cupertino

```
 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: Thank you, downgrade the package.. Its one of a good idea, but how can't I update the Dart SDK into the newest version?I just don't understand, eventho I did "Flutter Upgrade"... the dart sdk version still not the newest

Comment: do what I said and run flutter upgrade if you face with that 'Flutter is already up to date on channel stable' there is no problem no need to upgrade yet   if I helped you a little bit can you like my post –

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021-03-10 or earlier, it is no longer necessary to use cupertino_icons 1.0.0 or switch to the beta update channel (`flutter channel beta`). Just upgrade (`flutter upgrade`) and re-run `flutter pub get`. For details, see [issue 72231](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72231).

Comment: False. It is needed to change to dev branch: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72231#issuecomment-774627170